# Accordion For Loop JS Selector

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, accordion

I'm trying to connect an array of objects referring to SVG Icons in a for loop to an array of matching content by letting the for loop index act as a pairing mechanism. Both Array's log as identifying all the relevant objects but when I call the panel[i] changes I get that panel[i] is undefined? acc[i] seems to work just fine inside the for loop. How can I make sure the acc[i] event listeners pair up with their corresponding index position panels to then control css on the panels to change display from hidden to block?

Thanks!

```
const acc = document.querySelectorAll(".fas.fa-plus-circle.fa-3x");
const panel = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");
let i;
console.log(acc);
console.log(panel);
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    console.log(panel[i]);
    if (panel[i].style.display === "block") {
      panel[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel[i].style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Move `let` inside the `for` clause: you want a `i` variable that has block scope.

Comment: I prefer to have actual relationships between 2 connected elements. Like `<div class='panel' data-num='1' >` relates to `<i class='fas fa-plus-circle' data-num='1'>` through the dataset. Or even better the icon and the panel are inside of the same parent container, and you can reference them relatively, like `icon.closest('.container').querySelector('.panel')...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have declared `i` outside the `for` loop, there is only one `i` variable, and it will have become equal to `acc.length` when the loop has completed. So when you click, and the event handler is executed, that value of `i` is not what you want to have there.

To solve this, make `i` a block-scoped variable:

```
for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
```

Now each iteration of the loop will have its own `i` variable, which will retain its value. There will be an `i` that is 0, another that is 1, ...Etc. As a consequence the event handlers will each access the right `i` having the expected value.

Comment: Thanks for the explainer, deleting the global scope variable for 'i' and declaring 'let' inside the for loop immediately gave the results I was looking for.